# public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) method calling with several CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

**TASK:** I want to display a list of ListView and when you select an item to display the list of dialogue and display it in a list of another element (parent and child elements)

```
  static class GroupCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
    DB db;

    public GroupCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getGroupAll();

        return cursor;
    }
}


static class DetailCursorLoader extends CursorLoader{
    DB db;

    public DetailCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = db.getDetailAll();

        return cursor;
    }
}
```

**Now, The question is, how to handle the two Cursor?**, i.e . written in the following methods

> public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
>
> public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor data)
>
> public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader)

```
  @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
   
    return return new GroupCursorLoader(this, mDB);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    scAdapterForGroup.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.d(LOG, "onLoadReset");
}
```

Comment: you should write the content in english

Comment: Ask your question at http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
      if(id == GROUP_LOADER_ID) {
        return new GroupCursorLoader(this, mDB);       
      } else {
        return new DetailCursorLoader(this, mDB);
      }
    }

   @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
      if(loader instanceof GroupCursorLoader) {
        scAdapterForGroup.swapCursor(data);
      } else {
        scAdapterForDetails.swapCursor(data);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.d(LOG, "onLoadReset");
   }
```

[Answer question at ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488013/public-loadercursor-oncreateloaderint-id-bundle-args-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C?noredirect=1#comment570547_488013)